# Ansible EC2 Dynamic Inventory with host_vars

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I'm new to Dynamic Inventory with Ansible.

I have a playbook:
`hosts: tag_Name_abc`

Running this playbook does what it needs to correctly on the tagged EC2 instance. When I try to use `host_vars` I get `fatal: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'test_var' is undefined"}`

There is a file `host_vars/tag_Name_abc` files under the playbook file directory with contents `test_var: test_value`, but it's not picking up the variable.

Launching the playbook `ansible-playbook -i ec2.py myplaybook.yml`

Any advise would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dynamic inventory script `ec2.py` make **groups** with names `tag_key_value`.

To set inventory variables for groups, you should put them into `group_vars` folder.
`host_vars` is for host-level vars.

In your case, you should use `group_vars/tag_Name_abc` file.

Comment: Lifesaver! Thanks a mil